# Sorting numeric String in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Let's assume that I have the following `Dataset`:

```
+-----------+----------+
|productCode|    amount|
+-----------+----------+
|      XX-13|       300|
|       XX-1|       250|
|       XX-2|       410|
|       XX-9|        50|
|      XX-10|        35|
|     XX-100|       870|
+-----------+----------+
```

Where `productCode` is of `String` type and the `amount` is an `Int`.

If one will try to order this by `productCode` the result will be (and this is expected because of nature of `String` comparison):

```
def orderProducts(product: Dataset[Product]): Dataset[Product] = {
    product.orderBy("productCode")
}

// Output:
+-----------+----------+
|productCode|    amount|
+-----------+----------+
|       XX-1|       250|
|      XX-10|        35|
|     XX-100|       870|
|      XX-13|       300|
|       XX-2|       410|
|       XX-9|        50|
+-----------+----------+
```

How can I get an output ordered by `Integer` part of the `productCode` like below considering `Dataset` API?

```
+-----------+----------+
|productCode|    amount|
+-----------+----------+
|       XX-1|       250|
|       XX-2|       410|
|       XX-9|        50|
|      XX-10|        35|
|      XX-13|       300|
|     XX-100|       870|
+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the expression in the orderBy. Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("XX-13",300),("XX-1",250),("XX-2",410),("XX-9",50),("XX-10",35),("XX-100",870)).toDF("productCode", "amt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [productCode: string, amt: int]

scala> df.orderBy(split('productCode,"-")(1).cast("int")).show
+-----------+---+
|productCode|amt|
+-----------+---+
|       XX-1|250|
|       XX-2|410|
|       XX-9| 50|
|      XX-10| 35|
|      XX-13|300|
|     XX-100|870|
+-----------+---+


scala>
```

With window functions, you could do like

```
scala> df.withColumn("row1",row_number().over(Window.orderBy(split('productCode,"-")(1).cast("int")))).show(false)
18/12/10 09:25:07 WARN window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+-----------+---+----+
|productCode|amt|row1|
+-----------+---+----+
|XX-1       |250|1   |
|XX-2       |410|2   |
|XX-9       |50 |3   |
|XX-10      |35 |4   |
|XX-13      |300|5   |
|XX-100     |870|6   |
+-----------+---+----+


scala>
```

Note that spark complains of moving all data to single partition.

Comment: Nice and simple