# Sorting a dataset with concatenated string by splitting as well as a single string for column in spark

Tags: apache-spark, sql-order-by

I have a column which looks as below. It has data with **`:`** concatenated and some may be `null` and some a string as `N/A`

Sample data:

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
| 11:88  |
+--------+
| 1:45   |
+--------+
| 17:456 |
+--------+
| 2:45   |
+--------+
| 11:9   |
+--------+
| N/A    |
+--------+
```

I want to order it as ascending based on the first element  before `:` and **null** should be first and **N/A**  and then followed by the numerical order of the first element as below

Required data after ascending order :

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
| N/A    |
+--------+
| 1:45   |
+--------+
| 2:45   |
+--------+
| 11:88  |
+--------+
| 11:9   |
+--------+
| 17:456 |
+--------+
```

Similarly as below when in descending order

```
+--------+
| column |
+--------+
| 17:456 |
+--------+
| 11:9   |
+--------+
| 11:88  |
+--------+
| 2:45   |
+--------+
| 1:45   |
+--------+
| N/A    |
+--------+
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707368/sorting-numeric-string-in-spark-dataset) answer your question ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Partially, But I have an record as 'N/A' too

Comment: yes, I realised, but I think you can proceed from starting this point, don't you? Most probably you need a case when expression within the order by clause I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val df3 = Seq("11:88","1:45","17:456","2:45","11:9","N/A").toDF("column")  
scala> df3.show
+------+
|column|
+------+
| 11:88|
|  1:45|
|17:456|
|  2:45|
|  11:9|
|   N/A|
+------+  
scala> df3.withColumn("NEW",regexp_replace(col("column"),":",".").cast("Double")).orderBy(col("NEW").desc).drop("NEW").show
    +------+
    |column|
    +------+
    |17:456|
    |  11:9|
    | 11:88|
    |  2:45|
    |  1:45|
    |   N/A|
    +------+
 scala> df3.withColumn("NEW",regexp_replace(col("column"),":",".").cast("Double")).orderBy(col("NEW").asc).drop("NEW").show
    +------+
    |column|
    +------+
    |   N/A|
    |  1:45|
    |  2:45|
    |  11:9|
    | 11:88|
    |17:456|
    +------+
```

Please let me know if it helps you.

Comment: This is adding a new column which I want to avoid

Comment: You mean, don't want to use any withColumn operation.